# Lemma by Riemann-Lebesgue

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The purpose of this problem is that I want to prove that for any $\lambda$ integrable function $f$ on a bounded closed interval $[a, b]$ holds
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{[a, b]} f(x) \sin (n x) d \lambda=0.
$$

I have submitted a proof below.

Comment: Choose $\epsilon > 0, k$ such that $\int |f_k - f| < \epsilon$, and $n$ such that $\int f_k(x)\sin nx\,d\lambda < \epsilon$, then note that $$\left|\int f_k(x)\sin nx - f(x)\sin nx\,d\lambda\right| \le \int |f_k(x)\sin nx - f(x)\sin nx|\,d\lambda$$ and work from there. For the third step, it looks like a pretty straight-forward progression. Where are you not seeing what to do?

Comment: @PaulSinclair my only problem for the third step is that if I insert for example the indicator function for $f$, I need to integrate, right? Can I just convert it into a riemann integral? Or is there some missing reasoning.

Comment: When the Riemann integral exists, it is equal to the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I have used your hint. What do you think?

Comment: The only issue I see is the abhorrent notation $|f - f_k|(x)$! As for the integration, if you knew that $f$ was Riemann Integrable (or for the $1_A$ indicator function, that it was Riemann integrable), then yes, you can use the Riemann integral. But unfortunately, all you know is the $f$ is Lesbegue integrable and $A$ is Lesbegue measurable. $\mathbf 1_I$ is Riemann integrable, as is $\sin nx$, so step 1 is fine by Riemann. But the later steps need Lesbegue.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I adapted my proof but now it seems worse than before...

Comment: ?? I only criticized a single notational choice, not the logic, which was correct. Why would this make you massively rewrite the proof? At most you should have just changed that notation. And you would have been entirely justified in simply ignoring my opinion of that one notation. And it was just an opinion - if I had been serious about it, I would have explained my objection instead of simply calling it abhorrent. I'm sorry my comment caused you such confusion. Because $|\sin nx| \le 1$, the integral is majorized by $\int |f - f_k|$ as you had said before.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ok thank you, nothing to worry about, I still have the proof in my papers. I am working on those 4 statements now. :)

Comment: For step 2, since you know $A$ is Lesbegue measurable, there are countable collections of intervals that cover $A$, and the infimum of the total lengths of those collections will be $\lambda(A) = \int_{\Bbb R} \mathbf 1_A \,d\lambda$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I am stuck,I don't know how to show your hint. I dont even know if my proof for the second part is true.

Comment: I forget about the multiplication by $\sin nx$ before integrating in that, But I believe there is a theorem characterizing all measurable sets as differing from an open set by a set of measure $0$. The integrals of any function over two sets which differ by a set of measure $0$ will be the same. And every open set in $\Bbb R$ is a countable union of disjoint open intervals. Alas I am having trouble finding that characterization of measurable sets, but if you can find it, it provides a clear path to this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another is aproach of Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma.

The smooth functions with compact suppport $\mathcal{C}_0^{\infty}([a,b])$ functions are dense over the Lebesgue integral functions $L^1[a,b]$. Then for every $f$ there is a sequence $(f_{k})_k \subset \mathcal{C}_0^{\infty}([a,b]) $ such that $\|f-f_k\|_1 \xrightarrow{k\to \infty}{0}$. We observe that
\begin{align} 
\left | \int_a^b f_k(x)\sin(nx)dx \right|= \left| -\frac{1}{n} \int_a^b f_k'(x)\cos(nx)dx \right| = \frac{1}{n^2} \left| \int_a^b f_k''(x)\sin(nx)dx \right| \leq \frac{M_k}{n^2} \xrightarrow{n\to \infty}{0} 
\end{align}
Where $M_k = \sup_{x\in[a,b]} |f''_k(x)|(b-a) < \infty$. Now
\begin{align}
\left | \int_a^b f(x)\sin(nx)dx  \right| &\leq \left | \int_a^b f_k(x)\sin(nx)dx  \right|  + \left | \int_a^b (f(x)-f_k(x))\sin(nx)dx  \right|
\\
& \leq \frac{M_k}{n^2} + \|f_k-f\|_1 \xrightarrow{n\to \infty} \|f_k-f\|_1 \xrightarrow{k \to \infty} 0. 
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ denote the set of all $\lambda$-integrable functions $f$ on $[a, b]$ that satisfy this condition.

We prove this Lemma in 3 steps.

(a) We prove that a finite linear combination of functions from $G$ is also in $G$.

(b) We prove: if $\left\{f_{k}\right\}$ is a sequence of functions from $G$ and holds
$$
\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_{[a, b]}\left|f_{k}-f\right| d \lambda=0 .
$$
for a $\lambda$-integrable function $f$, then $f \in G$ holds.

(c) We show that the following functions $f$ are in $G$:

i. $f=\mathbf{1}_{I}$ for an interval $I \subset[a, b]$;

ii. $f=\mathbf{1}_{A}$ for a Lebesgue measurable set $A \subset[a, b]$;

iii. $f$ is an elementary function;

iv. $f$ is a $\lambda$-integrable function.

---

(a) If $\left\{f_{k}\right\}_{k=1}^{N}$ is a finite sequence of $G$, we obtain for its linear combination
$$
f=\sum_{k=1}^{N} \alpha_{k} f_{k} .
$$
Then follows
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{J} \sum_{k=1}^{N} \alpha_{k} f_{k}(x) \sin (n x) d \lambda=0 .
$$
And since the linear combination is finite, it is interchangeable with the integral, so we obtain
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{N} \alpha_{k} \int_{J} f_{k}(x) \sin (n x) d \lambda=0 .
$$
and for $n \rightarrow \infty$ the value of the integral goes towards 0, so the linear combination is again in $G$.

---

(b) We have
$$
\left|\int_{J} f(x) \sin (n x) d \lambda\right| \leq \int_{J}\left|f(x)-f_{k}(x)\right||\sin (n x)| d \lambda+\left|\int_{J} f_{k}(x) \sin (n x) d \lambda\right|
$$
from which it follows for $n \rightarrow \infty$ that
$$
\limsup _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|\int_{J} f(x) \sin (n x) d \lambda\right| \leq \int_{J}\left|f(x)-f_{k}(x)\right| d \lambda .
$$
Then for $k \rightarrow \infty$ we get
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{J} f(x) \sin (n x) d \lambda=0
$$
and therefore $f \in G$.

---

(c)

i. Let $I \subset J$ be an interval, e.g. $I=[a, \beta] .$ Then for the function $f=1_{I}$ holds.
$$
\int_{J} f(x) \sin (n x) d \lambda=\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} \sin (n x) d x=\frac{\cos (n \alpha)-\cos (n \beta)}{n} \rightarrow 0 \text { for } n \rightarrow \infty 
$$
such that $1_{I} \in G$. It follows that the function $1_{A}$ is also in $G$ if $A$ is a finite disjoint union of intervals.

ii. Let $A \subset J$ be a Lebesgue measurable set. By definition of measurable sets, for each $k$ there exists a set $A_{k}$ which is a finite disjoint union of intervals with
$$
\mu\left(A \vartriangle A_{k}\right)<\frac{1}{k} .
$$
Then
$$
\int_{J}\left|\mathbf{1}_{A}-\mathbf{1}_{A_{k}}\right| d \lambda=\mu\left(A \vartriangle A_{k}\right)<\frac{1}{k}
$$
from which follows
$$
\int_{J}\left|\mathbf{1}_{A}-\mathbf{1}_{A_{k}}\right| d \lambda \rightarrow 0 \text { for } k \rightarrow \infty .
$$
Since all $1_{A_{k}} \in G$ then $1_{A} \in G$.

iii. Every elementary function on $[a, b]$ is also in $G$ as a linear combination of indicator functions.

iv. For any non-negative $\lambda$-integrable function $f$, there is a sequence $\left\{\varphi_{k}\right\}$ of elementary functions with $\varphi_{k} \leq f, \varphi_{k} \rightarrow f$ which converges pointwise and it also holds that
$$
\int_{J} \varphi_{k} d \lambda \rightarrow \int_{J} f d \lambda .
$$
Since $f-\varphi_{k} \geq 0$, it follows that.
$$
\int_{J}\left|f-\varphi_{k}\right| d \lambda \rightarrow 0
$$
Since $\varphi_{k} \in G$, we obtain that $f \in G$ as well. Any (signed) $\lambda$-integrable function $f$ lies in $G$ as the difference $f_{+}-f_{-}$ of two functions $f_{+}$ and $f_{-}$from $G$.

$\quad \blacksquare$